# MySQL select for global sales report

Tags: mysql, sql, reportviewer

I have a web app in .Net with Reportviewer and I use as sourcedata of reportviewer MySql query, I need to make a global sales report I have this Table sales:

|IdSale|Number|Date|Price| etc...

(The important part of my problem is the next, i need to calculate the sum of price for each row with the same Number. Why? Well the Number datafield is the receipt or bill, so I can have one sale for the receipt / bill number 6 and i selled 2 items:

```
|IdSale|Number| Date |Price|

|  1   |  6   |20/08 |  50€|
|  2   |  6   |20/08 |  10€|
----------------------------
```

So i need to get the sum of that **but, with the others Numbers** i mean i can do that with this query:

```
Select distinct sales.Number, sales.Date, SUM(sales.Price) as 'Importe', 
from sales where number = 6;*
```

and return

```
|Number|Date|Importe(price)|
|  6   |20/8|    100€      |
```

That's ok but when i have this

```
|IdSale|Number| Date |Price|
|  1   |  6   |20/08 |  50€|
|  2   |  6   |20/08 |  10€|
|  3   |  7   |20/08 |  30€|
|  4   |  8   |20/08 |  20€|
----------------------------
```

I neet to get this output

```
|Number|Date|Importe(price)|
|  6   |20/8|    100€      |
|  7   |20/8|    30€       | 
|  8   |20/8|    20€       |
```

But the only thing i made is using this query

```
Select distinct sales.Number, sales.Date, SUM(sales.Price) as 'Importe', 
from sales where number >= 0;


|Number|Date|Importe(price|
|  2   |20/8| 150€        |
```

So im getting the sum of all but i just need the sum of each row with the same Number can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for `group by`?

```
Select s.Number, s.Date, SUM(s.Price) as Importe, 
from sales s
group by s.Number, s.Date;
```

Comment: But but but how can I be so STUPID? Really dude thank u, u save my life I was thinkin and testing a lot of things but more complicated i didnt even thought the simple part of SQL T_T now I need to try to put that in my full query (its kinda more complicated but i think i can do that alone... xD) really ty!